# Gremlin with java - Is it possible to overwrite the 'g' of gremlin server from java client with new TraversalStrategy enabled

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server

We are trying to apply a static filter based on user permission pre-set on the vertices as property.

Need some help in order to achieve the **#4** and **#5**

**Approach:**
**1.** Implement a gremlin proxy service (Java REST layer) enabling the SubgraphStrategy to create the GraphTraversalSource i.e. g on every request.

**2.** extract the user principle and invoke our entitlement service to get all the permissions.

**3.** use these user permissions to create a new GraphTraversalSource (g2) with SubgraphStrategy

**4.** Use this 'g2' to submit the requested gremlin query string to Gremlin server i.e. client.submit(queryString). *// is it possible?? how can we override the 'g' used in queryString with the new 'g2'*

**5.** Response should be in JSON (GraphSON) the same way gremlin server responds (Http response). How can we produce the similar JSON from the ResultSet.

### code snippet:
remote-objects.yaml (used to connect to gremlin server remotely via java)

```
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8183
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
```

// Should we change anything at this serializer? in order to serialize the server response in GraphSON?

### gremlin-server.yaml

```
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 8183
threadPoolWorker: 1
gremlinPool: 8
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
serializedResponseTimeout: 30000
#channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.HttpChannelizer
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WsAndHttpChannelizer
graphs: {
  graph: "H:\\project_work\\Gremlin-Graph\\src\\main\\resources\\janusgraph-cassandra-es.properties" }
scriptEngines: {
 gremlin-groovy: {
      plugins: { org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.plugin.JanusGraphGremlinPlugin: {},
                 org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {},
                 org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.jsr223.TinkerGraphGremlinPlugin: {},
                 org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin: {classImports: [java.lang.Math], methodImports: [java.lang.Math#*]},
                 org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {
                 files: ["H:\\project_work\\Gremlin-Graph\\src\\main\\resources\\empty-sample.groovy"]
                 }}
   }
}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0, config: {ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor, config: { cacheExpirationTime: 600000, cacheMaxSize: 1000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  gangliaReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000, addressingMode: MULTICAST},
  graphiteReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000}}
threadPoolBoss: 1
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
ssl: {
  enabled: false}
```

### janusgraph-cassandra-es.properties

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory

storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5,1.2.3.6,1.2.3.7,1.2.3.8,1.2.3.9
storage.username=username
storage.password=password
storage.read-time=20000 ms
storage.cql.keyspace=janusgraph_dev
storage.cql.read-consistency-level=LOCAL_QUORUM
storage.cql.write-consistency-level=LOCAL_QUORUM
storage.cql.local-datacenter=dc1
storage.cql.only-use-local-consistency-for-system-operations=true
storage.cql.replication-strategy-options=dc1,2,dc2,2
storage.cql.replication-strategy-class=NetworkTopologyStrategy
log.tx.key-consistent=true

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.index-name=graph_search_cs_dev
index.search.hostname=dev.elastic.service.com
index.search.elasticsearch.http.auth.type=custom
index.search.elasticsearch.http.auth.custom.authenticator-class=edu.sample.cassandra.graph.Authenticator
index.search.elasticsearch.http.auth.custom.authenticator-args=keytabUser,H:\\keytabs\\keytab-file.kt
```

### empty-sample.groovy is the default used here:

https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/static/scripts/empty-sample.groovy

### Java REST layer (Gremlin Proxy Service)

```
GET /gremlin-proxy?gremlin=g.V().has('name', 'stephane').out()


Cluster cluster = Cluster.open("H:\\project_work\\Gremlin-Graph\\src\\main\\resources\\remote-objects.yaml");
Client client = cluster.connect();
Graph graph = EmptyGraph.instance();
GraphTraversalSource g2 = graph.traversal()
.withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster, "g"))
.withStrategies(SubgraphStrategy.build().vertices(has("p_entitlements",textContains("edu.sample.graph.team2"))).create());


String queryString = "g.V().has('uri', 'http://sample.com/sample/sample_2').out()"; *// user requested query string. Is it possible to replace this 'g' with the new GraphTraversalSource i.e. 'g2' for the server to use and execute.*

ResultSet rs = client.submit(queryString);

System.out.println(rs);

List<Result> results = rs.all().get();  *// Unsure how we can convert this to GraphSON like gremlin server response in JSON*

System.out.println(results);

g.close();
client.close();
cluster.close();
```

Any reference or pointers would very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overwrite `g` in the ways you are describing. I can think of two options:

1. [Use a session](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#sessions), construct `g` as you wish and then reference that `g` in that session, OR
2. Build your query string with the `SubgraphStrategy` code for each request. That should not be a terribly expensive operation in my mind if you had to do it.

Comment: Thanks Stephen as always.
ConcurrentBindings b = new ConcurrentBindings();b.putIfAbsent("g", g);
GremlinExecutor ge = GremlinExecutor.build().evaluationTimeout(15000L).globalBindings(b).create();
CompletableFuture<Object> evalResult = ge.eval("g.V().hasLabel('person').valueMap()");GraphTraversal actualResult = (GraphTraversal) evalResult.get(); ResultSet rs = client.alias("g").submit("g.V().has('name', 'stephen').out()"). List<Result> results = rs.all().get(); This works. but now the #5 above how can I convert into GraphSON.

Comment: just create a `GraphSONMapper` instance and use that: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/eb0813e007e5c3218742e19f955cb3db8026c29b/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/io/graphson/GraphSONMapper.java

Comment: List<Result> results = resultSet.all().get(); ObjectMapper om = GraphSONMapper.build().version(GraphSONVersion.V1_0).create().createMapper(); System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(results)). This throws error says: DefaultRemoteTraverser cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.Property

Comment: I don't think you can serialize a `Result`. There is no serializer for it. You have to serialize the thing inside the `Result`. `Result` has methods like `getObject()` which should return that object.

Comment: Could see that the result now satisfying the Subgraphstrategy and returning 1  adjacent node but the result is of type DefaultRemoteTraverser and the DetachedVertex within it has only id and label populated BUT the properties is null. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Also using V2_0 works i.e. GraphSONMapper.build().version(GraphSONVersion.V2_0).create().createMapper(); but if I change that to V1_0 returns Error. "This operation does not support features. org.apache.....DefaultRemoteTraverser"

Comment: V1 doesn't have serializers to support `Traverser` serialization I guess. I'm not sure I understand your code anymore to be honest as it has a `GremlinExecutor` in it and I don't know what that has to do with the situation. You typically shouldn't be seeing a `Traverser` object. That should be unwrapped on the client side into the containing object, but for some reason that is not happening. I'm not sure what puts you in that position.

Comment: The `DetachedVertex` is expected - https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_properties_of_elements and https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/e959e85d4f8b3d46d281f2742a6e574c7d27c54bfc52f802f7c04af3%40%3Cdev.tinkerpop.apache.org%3E